# How can I add more raster to a stack of raster that already has some raster files in R?

Tags: r, stack, raster

I have a raster stack named `rstack`:

```
rstack <- list.files(path) #path contains the location of the directory
```

Now I have another raster file named `araster`.

How do I add this new raster `araster` into the stack `rstack`?

I have spent a lot of time searching for this online but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `addLayer` function to add new raster files to an existing stack.

```
library(raster)
rstack <- addLayer(rstack,araster)
```

Comment: Can you please provide the package addLayer belongs to?

Comment: @deschen It belongs to the `raster` package.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I'm following your question correctly, but f you are merely want to combine both stacks, it should simply work with `c`.

```
rstack   <- list.files()
newstack <- list.files()

combined_stack <- c(rstack, newstack)
```

Comment: I don't think this is what he meant by adding a raster to an existing stack. You are just combining both stacks and here the new stack will not be added into the existing stack.

Comment: But how is that conceptually different? In my code I could easily have said `rstack <-c(rstack, newstack)`.

Comment: `c()` returns a list. `addlayer` basically returns it as a Formal class RasterStack. Stacking raster layers are usually done using the `stack()` function and not using `list()`.

Comment: Then I might have misread the TOs question. The object `rstack` is just a character vector containing file names. And I interpreted the question in a way that the TO just wants to add other file names/paths to this rstack object.

Comment: Yeah. Now that you've mentioned it. The question needs clarification. I can see that TO is trying to combine a character vector.